# Javascript API to convert voice to text

Tags: ios, safari, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

Are there any API for converting voice to text. I found few of them like ArtyOm.js, Speech API etc. But, they are only compatible with Chrome browser. Are there any which works on both Safari and Chrome or only on Safari.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition), you will see, speech recognition not work in Safari/IOS Browser. You have to wait for updates...